# How to override OrderRepositry - save function | API

Tags: repository, override-model, interface

I need to add some custom functionalities in the Order save function when some API request comes. To be exact need to override the core OrderRepository class
***vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/OrderRepository.php***.
Below are the code I used for override using around plugin. and faced the error as

> **"Missing required argument $resourceClassName of Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata."**

**Sample/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<!--  Cancel Order Sync with Magento from Shiprocket -->
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository">
        <plugin name="Order_save_function_modify"
                type="Sample\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\OrderRepository"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Sample\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\OrderRepository.php

```php
<?php

namespace Sample\ModuleName\Plugin\Model;

use Closure;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository as Subject;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata;

class OrderRepository
{
    protected $registry = [];
    /**
     * @var Metadata
     */
    private $metadata;

    public function __construct(Metadata $metadata)
    {
        $this->metadata = $metadata;
    }

    public function aroundSave(Subject $subject, Closure $proceed, $entity)
    {
        $extensionAttributes = $entity->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($entity->getIsNotVirtual() && $extensionAttributes && $extensionAttributes->getShippingAssignments()) {
            $shippingAssignments = $extensionAttributes->getShippingAssignments();
            if (!empty($shippingAssignments)) {
                $shipping = array_shift($shippingAssignments)->getShipping();
                $entity->setShippingAddress($shipping->getAddress());
                $entity->setShippingMethod($shipping->getMethod());
            }
        }
        $this->metadata->getMapper()->save($entity);
        $this->registry[$entity->getEntityId()] = $entity;

        // My custom logics
        
       return $this->registry[$entity->getEntityId()];
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's just extension attribute then you should mainly work with extension attribute, no need to add registry as some kind of storage, extension attribute provide a clearer way to work with it (plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are better off using a preference? Then you wouldn't need to redefine metadata yourself.

Otherwise, original order repository has this in di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="object">orderMetadata</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

orderMetadata resolves to (no need to copy, just for reference):

```
<virtualType name="orderMetadata" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="resourceClassName" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
        <argument name="modelClassName" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\Order</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

I reckon you need to pass the same argument to your plugin:

```
<type name="Sample\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\OrderRepository">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="object">orderMetadata</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

If you are using PhpStorm, I strongly recommend activating standard Magento 2 plugin that will highight such di.xml references.
[image: order repository hints]